# Downloading a specific part of a html doc after waiting 10sec using php

Tags: javascript, php

I’m new at using PHP but I’m searching for a very specific function and I don’t know if PHP would be able to do what I want.

I would like to load a HTML page, wait several seconds (in order to allow JavaScript to make change on the page), and then download the content that changed.

For example there is a HTML doc which has a `<video>` tag that is changing its `src` attribute every 10 seconds (with JavaScript) and the thing I want to do is to grab using PHP all those `src` in one script.

I know that it’s possible to download the first attribute, I’ve done some research and it seems that I should use the `get_file(url)` function, but I don’t know if it is even possible to load the doc, wait until the attribute changes and then download the changed attribute.

Comment: PHP can download the HTML for you, but it will not **process** it. It will not download any resources linked in the HTML (like stylesheets, javascript files, images, etc.) and it will not execute javascript code.

Comment: PHP does not natively execute JavaScript. When you get the page with php, you are getting the rendered html. The Javascript will not be executed. Instead, look at how the page changes the url in the first place.

Comment: Go with puppeteer and Nodejs.

Answer (score 3):

This is not, as you've described it (that is, assuming that the `src` attribute really is changed by JavaScript), something that PHP can do on its own. PHP doesn't run JavaScript, browsers do. Once your PHP code downloads the HTML, what you have is simply a string of characters; PHP alone doesn't know any difference between that and "hello world". It's not going to change in memory, no matter how long you wait.

But all is not lost. You should look at the HTML and JavaScript of the page, this may give you some ideas about how to proceed. The JavaScript must be getting the new `src` from somewhere, right? The only obvious options are that it's already embedded in the source somewhere (an array of sources, for example, which it cycles through) or it's being retrieved from a server via Ajax. If it's the former, you can just directly extract that list right away, no waiting required. If it's the latter, you may be able to send your own queries to the server to get them all, though there are security things that could cause problems here.

Comment: Thant you for your answer :) unfortunately there is some security settings that does not allow me to get the ressource like this

Answer (score 0):

To do what you're seeking, you'll need a browser engine that can execute JavaScript just like what would happen with real users.

Look into a headless browser, such as SlimerJS, or one of the many headless Chromium APIs.  You can tell the browser engine to load a page and execute its scripts.  After some time (or a certain trigger), you can use the DOM API just like you would in-browser.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I will look at slimerJS and chromium :)